# Should I leave a question open that I have just edited?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing

I have just edited this question: [Buying an eight-year-old car with very low mileage?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22152/buying-an-eight-year-old-car-with-very-low-mileage), as it has several close votes, to try and make it more specific.

However, the edit has not been approved yet, and I am reviewing close votes.

Should I leave it open, vote to close or skip it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately this is up to you to decide. If you agree with the others who have thrown a close vote on the question, then vote to close yourself. I often will check when reviewing the close votes to see what others have already done to see if I do agree with them. Most of the time I do agree with them and vote to close. Other times I disagree and obviously vote to leave it open. Very infrequently will I skip the question (at least on the close vote review queue).

This is the whole reason why there are review queues and that most of those review queues require five votes to close a question for which ever reason. I know this is a really wishy-washy answer, but it *really is up to you*.

Realistically, though, if you just edited it to try and salvage the question, you must believe there is some merit in it, so personally in that situation I would vote to leave open, but that's just me.

Comment: In the end I left it open. Thanks :)